# how to Download a pdf file from server to sd card using android + unity

Tags: c#, android, pdf, download, unity-game-engine

i am trying to download a file from a webserver (a pdf file) and saved into my sd card, or dirrectly atachment this file to and email and send the email after that.

My application need to send an email to some students with some information in pdf i am already send email with subject and contend but cause i am using unity + android i cant download and/or read a pdf file.

i am trying with the WWW class but is not working

```
if(loadInfo.getPantallaActual().Equals("pantallaInicio"))
{   
Email objEmail =    LoadCarreras.objXML.objCarrera.GetEmail();
string to = "to@hotmail.com";
string from = "from@gmail.com";
string subject =     objEmail.GetAsunto();
string body = objEmail.GetCuerpo();
string urlAttachment =   objEmail.GetContenido_url();
StartCoroutine(descarga(urlAttachment));
archivo =    Path.GetFileName(urlAttachment);
File.CreateText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+archivo);
                    Debug.Log(" urlAttachment "+urlAttachment);
                    Debug.Log(" archivo "+archivo);
                    Debug.Log(" persistentDataPath "+Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+archivo);

                         message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);


                        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                        client.EnableSsl = true;
                        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        client.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost) new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "pasw.");
                        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
                        client.Timeout = 10000;

                        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
                        delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
                            { return true; };

                        try {
                            client.Send(message);
                        }
                            catch (System.Exception ex) {
                            Debug.Log("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage1(): "+ex.ToString() );
                        }   


public IEnumerator descarga(string url){

    descargaA = new WWW(url);
    mandarEmail = true; 
    yield return descargaA;
}
void Update () {
    if(mandarEmail)
    {
        if(descargaA.isDone && cambiar){


            message.Attachments.Add (new Attachment(Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+"file.pdf"));  
            cambiar = false;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes IOException: Sharing violation on path C:\Users\jonymanolo\AppData\LocalLow\UDEM\carreRA\archivoAdjunto.pdf

Comment: So the problem is in the function 'descarga'? Or where is the exception thrown. Have you tried saving it to another path: C:\bla.pdf

Comment: i need to save on the sd card of android

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.